# Action trigger when something is selected in a TextView - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I want to call an action when you select something in a textview, same thing as the default actions for copying, pasting etc.

I tried with this and it works fine,

```
    override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    callAction()
    return false
}
```

but the problem is, I'm using a secondary keyboard for additional inputs, and when I display the secondary keyboard (above the standard keyboard) the action that I want to call when something is selected (in this case callAction() in canPerformAction) is performed.

So, what's the best way to call an action when a text is selected in a textview?

Comment: Can you not look more closely at the sender, the objects being sent. Surely the system can detect the difference between the primary on screen keyboard and an external one?

Comment: I tried with:

let selectedRange = self.composeTextView.selectedTextRange
        let selectedText : String = composeTextView.textInRange(selectedRange!)!
        
        if(selectedText != "")
        {
            callAction()
        }
It works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let selectedRange = self.composeTextView.selectedTextRange let selectedText : String = composeTextView.textInRange(selectedRange!)! if(selectedText != "") { callAction() }
```